# Installation of Meanings failed on Nexus 4

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm doing a simple test with the tutorial app 'Meanings'. It's running fine in the emulator but fails if I try to install the 'click' package on the physical device.

```
Executing: /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.knitzsche.meanings_0.1_all.click
Launcher PID: 11155
AppId: com.ubuntu.developer.knitzsche.meanings_meanings_0.1
Architecture: all
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Waiting for authentication
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Results:
Fatal error: /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.knitzsche.meanings_0.1_all.click failed to install.
Cannot install /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.knitzsche.meanings_0.1_all.click: Signature verification error: debsig: Origin Signature check failed. This deb might not be signed.
Installing the application failed
```

Seem's something with the package signing is wrong.
The same thing is happen if I run 'click verify ' on the device.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solved the issue by installing the "devel-proposed" image on the device.